# The swift compiler always 100% CPU

Tags: ios, swift, cpu, freeze

I just added a Swift extension in my old Objective-C app. The Swift compiler is always at 100% CPU and hangs after I had run several times. I had tried restarting the Mac, but it's still the same.
I run Xcode6-Beta2 on OSX 10.9.3. Thanks.

Update:
I found these code cause this issue:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() 
let lastURLBase: String? = defaults.objectForKey("HP-lastURLBase") as String?
```

Comment: Can you see anything in the console? `/Applications/Utility/Console.app`

Comment: I can't see anything in the console related it. I had re-install it, and still not work.

Comment: try building a demo app. It my be a code specific compiler bug.

Comment: I think, it's only beta now and can contains some bugs. Wait for release.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert, yes, after investigate, I found these codes cause the 100% CPU：        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let lastURLBase: String? = defaults.objectForKey("HP-lastURLBase") as String?
I can repro it in my 2 Mac machine.

Comment: You should file a Radar to get it fixed. It's probably a bug!

Comment: I've run into similar issues and filed it with Radar a month ago. So far my radar hasn't been processed yet. Presumably Apple is aware of it since many people have run into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second line should be: `let lastURLBase = defaults.stringForKey("HP-lastURLBase")`. A constant (`let`) can't be optionally typed (`?`).